# Showing all entries after a certain time

Tags: php, mysql, contao

I currentluy use this custom SQL in Contao SQL to display all entries (metamodel) that are in the future.

```
SELECT * FROM {{table}} WHERE party_date > UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
```

Now when I have a entry (party) which is scheduled for 2017/03/28 it won't be displayed when its 2017/03/29.
But how can I keep this entry up until 2017/03/29 - 04:00am in the morning?

Visitors of the website should see this partry up until 4am in the morning (event site).

Is it possible with UNIX_TIMESTAMP() ?

Comment: Whats the datatype of party_date in your table? Could you post the result of "SHOW CREATE TABLE {{table}}"

Comment: Yes it is possible; consult the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp - there are examples in there.

Comment: @Marek123 do you always want to keep 4 hours difference in date/time range?

Comment: @DarshanMehta yes. party_date is "datetime"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to have 4 hours' gap, you can subtract 4 hours from current datetime and compare the `DATE` part of `party_date` and `NOW()`, e.g.:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE DATE(party_date) >= DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 4 HOUR))
```

By this logic, `2017/03/29 - 04:00am` would result in 2017/03/29 and as it's same as `date` part of `party_date`, it will be displayed.

[Here's](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) MySQL's documentation for datetime functions.

Comment: That helped me:
SELECT * FROM {{table}} WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(party_date) >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 4 HOUR)

Comment: party_date was a bigint instead of datetime... my fault. The metalmodels extension is very weird with the datatypes.

Comment: It is using the same type as Contao does everywhere. dates are stored as timestamp and therefore you need to wrap with `FROM_UNIXTIMESTAMP`calls in the query.